# Count hours, minutes, and seconds between two dates in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to count how many hours, minutes and seconds between two dates.

For example: Date 1: `01-01-1990 12:00` and `01-02-1990 13:00`

Now, how many hours, minutes, and second from date 1 to date 2 using php?

Comment: Did you look at: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php ?

Comment: Yes,but it doesn't work.I was still learning

Answer (score 0):

just use strtotime() on your dates to their timestampz . and then subtract them to have the difference in the number of seconds.  it's easy to convert from there

Comment: Please,Write it in php for me :(